# Presentation layer / Public Services layer. A common term?

Tags: architecture, layer, nomenclature, presentation-layer, service-layer

While defining our application architecture (which contains both web UI and external web services) we stumbled upon our inability to find a common name for the topmost layer.
It is quite clear that there are DAL (data access layer) and BLL (business logic layer) in our application. On the top of BLL, there reside the UI, which is commonly called the presentation  layer (e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647339.aspx). But there's also a service layer, which resides on the top of BLL as well!

But a cake can't have two layers on the same level :) So please help me to find a term for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term API (Application Programming Interface) is commonly used for programming interfaces, though in this case "Service Layer" may be more appropriate and descriptive.

Layers can be side by side - nothing says they *have* to be one on top of another.

Comment: API and "Service Layer" can be terms for web services. But what about the UI part? I'd like to have a common term.
And in my world layers have to be on the top of each other. Service layer and web presentation are in one layer, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @Shedal - If you can see it and interact with it, it belongs to the Presentation Layer.

Answer (score 0):

Presentation Layer is the one I've heard most for the layer containing UI components.

Comment: Yes, but what about a common term for Ui and services?

Answer (score 0):

What about Outer Layer? Top Layer? The Layer-that-shall-not-be-named?